# find inverse/mirror pair and assign a pair number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying  to find the inverse pair and assign a pair number to the pair but am stuck for moving forward from the below.

df1:

```
col1    col2  no. of records
A       B     2
B       A     5
C       D     4
D       C     6
E       F     4
G       H     6
```

I am trying get this result.

```
col1    col2  pair 1  no. of records    totalcount
A       B     1       2                 7
B       A     1       5                 7
C       D     2       4                 10
D       C     2       6                 10
E       F     3       4                 4
G       H     4       6                 6
```

I tried this method but it has only returned true/false.
to make a duplicate dataframe df2 and use isin function but was stucked for a long time while group them together.

```
df1['row_matched'] = np.where((df1.col1+df1.col2).isin(df2.col2+ df2.col1), df2['row'], "")
```

will appreciate any help available!

Comment: How can does the `totalcount` come? is pair + no of recordings?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rank` of group pair of `col1, col2`, which you could setup with `set`

```
In [37]: df['pair'] = (df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(set(x[['col1', 'col2']])), 1)
                         .rank(method='dense').astype(int))

In [38]: df['totalcount'] = df.groupby('pair')['no.ofrecords'].transform('sum')

In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
  col1 col2  no.ofrecords  pair  totalcount
0    A    B             2     1           7
1    B    A             5     1           7
2    C    D             4     2          10
3    D    C             6     2          10
4    E    F             4     3           4
5    G    H             6     4           6
```